# get xml data from bugzilla url

Tags: bugzilla

I am trying to get the xml data from the buglist.cgi file without success. After i have got the bugs I need in the form of xml displayed,

```
buglist.cgi?xyz_param=xyz_value&ctype=csv
```

gives me a csv of the values but,

```
buglist.cgi?xyz_param=xyz_value&ctype=xml
```

gives me this error

```
The requested format does not exist with a content type of xml.
```

However there is a small xml icon at the bottom of buglist page, when I click it , it generates an xml output that i want. Am I missing something here?

Bugzilla version : 3.4.3

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Adding the query parameter `ctype=rdf` will give you xml formatted output for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
buglist.cgi?xyz_param=xyz_value&ctype=rss
```

The rss format is xml. So do the search you want to get the results for and then add '&ctype=rss' to the end and that should get you xml output of that query.

Comment: This does not give XML, this gives RSS, which is accidentally XML but contains the relevant information as HTML only. To parse the data you'll first need to parse the XML and then parse the HTML in the `<summary>` tag of an entry. Surely not something you like to do.